# $f(x)=-4x^2+11126x-62516$. Time and how many

Tags: derivatives

The question is this I've been trying to get my head around this but simply cannot and am hoping you might get me going.

Q: The Store is open from $8$ am-$8$ pm every single day. $X$ represents the hours, $f(x)$ is how many customers there are.

What time can you mathematically presume the most customers arrived and how many customers are there?

Comment: so your f(x)=4x^2+11126x-62516 right?

Comment: Is $x$ the number of hours since 8 or the hour of the day? Also, you provided 3 functions...

Comment: ohhhh, I think mathguy is right.

Comment: X is the number of hours, So beginning with 8am going to 8pm and all those hours in between. The function is f(x)=-4x^2+111,26x-625,16.

Comment: the question requires derivatives

Comment: @HowardEllsworth Wait, you didn't answer the question. Is 8 A.M. $x=0$ or $x=8$? In addition, what's $f(x)=-4x^2+111,26x-625,16$? You mean $f(x)=-4x^2+111.26x-625.16$?

Comment: @Shahar I would guess $x=0 $ is $8$am. since we're counting the number hours it's open. If it was x=8, how would you represent minutes seconds etc?

Comment: @snulty From the answer, however, it doesn't seem like it. Look below.

Comment: @Shahar yeh I suppose so. Having the maximum amount of customers when you were closed wouldn't dwell well for a shop.

Comment: Thanks all, but it seems that Shahar understood somewhat what I was going with it, sorry for all the confusion regarding the [,].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=-4x^2+111.26x-625.16$$
The commas threw me *way* off. Perhaps it's different in other countries, but when you want to say $\frac12$ as a decimal, for example, it will be $0.5$. That's just a tip for later. For example: $14.342,343$ is $14,342.343$ here in the U.S. and in most places around the world.

Anyhow, for this problem, what we want to find is the *maximum* of $f(x)$ in that interval. Perhaps the first thing we should look for is absolute maximums.

Absolute maximums are when the slope is equal to $0$, and when the slope of that slope is *decreasing* (goes from positive to negative). In other words, $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x) < 0$. Or you can just check that $f'(x)$ goes from positive to negative.

$$f'(x)=-8x+111.26$$
$$f''(x)=-8$$

I'm assuming you know how to differentiate... It seems that the slope is always decreasing, so whatever we find for $f'(x)=0$ is going to be an absolute maximum. Let's solve it then:

$$0=-8x+111.26$$
$$x=13.9075$$

That's our answer. Anything to the right or left of it will be lower (because the second derivative is negative). That's our time: $13.9075=13:54:27\approx 1:54\text{ P.M.}$ That's another thing, in America we don't use a 24-hour clock. We denote morning as A.M. and afternoon as P.M. For example: 14:53 is 2:53 P.M.

Comment: How are you getting the minutes and seconds though? $.9075\cdot 60$ for the minutes? The $.45\cdot60$ for the left over seconds right?

Comment: (+1) though anyway for the good answer

Comment: @snulty Yeah. I initially thought it was .45 times 100 (milliseconds, forgot that this was seconds) but yeah it's 60. Double checked: http://www.springfrog.com/converter/decimal-time.htm And thanks for up vote :D.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Since $f(x)$ denotes the number of customers, in order to find the *most customers*, you need to calculate the maximum value that $f$ takes within its domain (from 8 in the morning until 8 at night). Then, the particular $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)$ is maximum, will be the time when most customers arrived.